# Julia Plots.jl: changing marker colour from series recipe

Tags: julia, plots.jl

I am trying to put together a `Plots.jl` user recipe, that would create several scatter plots and histograms arranged in a grid. The scatter plots should occupy the lower triangle of the grid. Histograms go on the diagonals. Each scatter plot should have several series, shown in different colours. The colours should be consistent across subplots.

My problem is when I allow the user to specify custom colours, the series colours in the scatter subplots get messed up.

Here is the (abridged) recipe code. `data` is is a vector of size `r`. Each element of `data` is a matrix of size `n_r x d`. `n_r` may vary, `d` stays the same. There should be `d x (d-1) / 2` scatter plots, with `r` series on each plot, each series having `n_r` points.

```
@recipe function my_func(data::my_type; custom_colors=nothing)
    # get d, r, ...
    for i in i:d
        for j in 1:d
            @series begin
                subplot := (i - 1) * d + j
                if i == j
                    seriestype := :histogram
                    plot_data = # ... prepare data for histograms
                elseif j < i
                    # scatter subplot recipe
                    seriestype := :scatter
                    if custom_colors !== nothing
                        color := reshape(custom_colors, (1, r))
                    end
                    x = Vector()
                    y = Vector()
                    for r in runs
                        ser = data[r]
                        append!(x, [ser[:, j]])
                        append!(y, [ser[:, i]])
                    end # for r
                    plot_data = (x, y)
                else
                    # leave empty
                    plot_data = [0]
                end #  if/else
                plot_data  # return from the macro function
            end # @series
        end # for j
    end # for i
end # @recipe
```

My problem is that whenever I supply custom colours, I get inconsistency across subplots:

```
plot(my_data, custom_colors=["blue", "green", "black"])
```

[image: plot with custom colors]

Note how subplot (2, 1) has black dots in the middle, whereas all other scatter subplots have black on the outside

If I do the plot without custom colors:

```
plot(my_data)
```

I get consistent colours in all scatter subplots:

[image]

Any clues why the colours are mixed up on the first plot?

Comment: Related comment. The plot recipe you are defining is called a corner plot. I was writing one myself to share as a package, but since you already have a good one ready, that is even better. Notice that there is a plot recipe for it in StatPlots.jl https://github.com/JuliaPlots/StatPlots.jl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, turns out the trick here is that each series on each scatter plot should be plotted with its own macro. In other words, the `@series ... end` should go inside `for r in runs ... end`. And a separate `@series` macro for each of the other branches of the code.